# It keeps duplicating textboxes when using jquery .on() function

Tags: jquery

I have 2 problem that needs to be addressed.

Problem 1:

In my jsfiddle I have a feature where the user opens a grid and selects an option, after the user selects an option then if they click on the "Add question" button, then this will be displayed in the new table row.

The only thing though is that I want the user to be able to open the grid and select an option from the table row (working exactly the way as select an option from above) just in case the user changes their mind and wants to select a different option within a row. I am using the .on() functions.

Does anyone know why it is not opening the grid?

Problem 2:

If the user adds a row by clicking on the "Add Question", it shows the option textbox once for the first row, if the user adds another row then it shows 2 options textboxes, then it shows 4 textboxes if 3rd row is added and etc.

Why is it doing this?

my code is in jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f8cKm/5/)

If anybody wants to look at the code then access the jsfiddle, if anybody knows the solution or wants to try the solution, they can use the jsfiddle.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly follow for your first question, could you explain a bit more?

Problem 2:

Every time you click the button, you call 'insertQuestion', however this functions looks up all elements with class `gridTxt`, and creates an input for each one, but that new one ALSO has gridTxt. I can't figure out why it does that, but that is the problem.

The first time you press add, it creates one because there is one gridTxt. The second time you press it there are now two gridTxt inputs, so it will create two. The third time you press it, it will loop 4 times and create 4 new boxes making a total of 8.